# Understanding the Relationship Between Limit Points and Boundary Points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In topology, I've encountered the lemma ∂(∂A) = ∂A when ∂A has an empty interior. I'm curious if a similar relationship holds for the set of limit points.

Is there a condition under which A' equals (A')'? Or is this statement always true?

Thank you for the insights

Comment: If $A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N,n>0\}$ then $A'=\{0\}$ and $A''=\{\}$.